# Python Error 123 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to make directory using os.mkdir in python

It works fine when path is `D:\screenshots\data`

```
os.mkdir("D:\screenshots\data")
```

but it gives error when path is `D:\screenshots\subs:air.com.freshplanet.games.MoviePop:moviepop.vip.1month`

```
os.mkdir("D:\screenshots\subs:air.com.freshplanet.games.MoviePop:moviepop.vip.1month")
[Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'D:\\screenshots\\subs:air.com.freshplanet.games.MoviePop:moviepop.vip.1month'
```

I don't know why it is giving this error

Comment: colons are not allowed in filenames in windows

Comment: thanx @FranciscoCouzo Now it works.

Comment: @Francisco Couzo is correct. Additionally, when you deal with windows filepaths, you should use the r"C:\mypath\containing\backslashes" syntax, that will avoid backslashes to be interpreted as special characters.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced a similar error while working in jupyter notebook.similar to
`OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:`
And i figured it out to be a double slash instead of single. I don't know why i had to give double back slash(\) instead of single. How ever it solved my problem Even before a day i used the same single back slash() to change directory. Please comment if someone knows about it.

Comment: You need to use single quotes or a raw string, not double quote

Comment: @cricket_007: Are you mixing things up with shell quoting syntax? Single quotes and double quotes do the same kind of quoting in Python.

Comment: @user235 they're not the same for escape characters

Comment: @cricket_007: [That doesn't sound right.](https://ideone.com/4eZ72T)

Comment: @cricket_007: Yeah, but that's not because of any difference in backslash handling. You can't end either a single-quoted string or a double-quoted string with a single backslash. Backslashes are escape characters either way.